# How do I get info on the requesting service when using Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

I was wondering whether Autofac allows me to grab information about the requesting context so I can modify my resulting service for the respective binding based on it.

For example something like this:

```
builder.Register(ctx =>
    {
        var name = ctx.Request.Name; // How do I do something like this?
        return new MyService(name);
    })
    .As<IMyService>()
    .SingleInstance();


public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IMyService myService)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this context, I would like to infer information about the calling context into a specific service (For e.g. logging purposes), but I didn't find any information on how Autofac would allow me to do such a thing. Basically, I would like to get a hold of the MyClass type in this case, but since I don't know upfront who might use the IMyService binding, I can't hardcode it.

Apparently Autofac does allow conditional binding, but the requesting side always has to provide metadata, so the flow is kind of turned the other way round.

I've used other IoC containers like Ninject before, and for Ninject it was simply included in one of the parameters of the lambda registration.

Is this possible?

Comment: not sure what exactly you need but you can inject the "IComponentContext" in any constructor, mabye you can use something from that?

Comment: @Kenion I added some explanation to hopefully make it a bit clearer

Comment: Soo... there is 'sort of' a way you can get this sort of info, but it might be a bit brittle, because it's dependent on some of the internal behaviour (also, on phone, so can't confirm).  Try casting the IComponentContext arg to 'ResolveRequestContext'. That class has an Operation property, which in turn has a "InProgressRequests" property, which should let you access the stack of in-flight requests. Each entry in that list has a Registration property that says what was resolved at each point in the stack.

Comment: Why so complicated, you ask? Because to be honest it can often be an anti-pattern to understand the caller in order to customise the service. Logging "might" be an exception to that, but certainly "here be dragons".